# Can you register parachains with custom code on Rococo?

Tags: rococo

I can see this phrase, while I am building 3 parachains on rococo testnet.
Are there any ways to use the different runtime codes customized for each parachain?
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can deploy parachains with different runtimes on Rococo testnet. Please take a look at [this tutorial](https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/connect-relay-and-parachains/acquire-a-testnet-slot/) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Adam Wierzbicki.

Your help is really valuable for me, then another question I have for now. I am going to build the 3 parachains for my project, and am using the substrate-parachain-template GitHub repository for testing. They have to communicate with each other via XCMP, therefore, I want to build the 3 parachain template projects, and to test how they simultaneously work on rococo local testnet.

Comment: Here, the issue I've faced is; When I use 2 validator nodes(running by Alice and Bob account) and 1 collator node(of 1 parachain), I can see my parachain builds the blocks successfully(like the guidance in the parity tech documentation). But when I use more than 2 validator nodes(running by Alice, Bob, Charles etc) and more than 1 collator node(of the other parachains), any blocks are not built by the parachains while I can't find any YouTube tutorials or specific documentation guidance.

Comment: Of course I know it's came by the lack of my knowledge, but I love Polkadot very much, but also want to become a good engineer in it's ecosystem. I am looking forward to your help if you could share your time for me.

Thanks, Stephen.

Comment: Honestly, there might many possible reasons and it I'm not sure if I would be able to debug this, but maybe try double-checking if you haven't messed up anything with the parachain IDs. Make sure you have reserved two ParaIds and passed them correctly to the parachain specs, as well as registration calls.

Comment: Absolutely, I can't show you here what I've done specifically for building my project. If you provide me any links of video or document explaining the steps to build 2-3 parachains with 3-4 validator nodes, they will exactly help me.

Comment: This may help: https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/4692/how-do-i-spin-up-a-testnet-with-zombienet