# Running a local network with zombienet doesn't work

Tags: zombienet

I am trying to create a local network natively. I followed the instructions from [here](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/4692/how-do-i-spin-up-a-testnet-with-zombienet) and I am running into a problem.

I built Polkadot and the substrate parachain template by running: `cargo build --release`

I copied the `config.toml` file and run:

```
zombienet-macos -p native spawn config.toml
```

When I run the command it initially looks like everything is working fine but at the end I get a pretty unclear error.

EDIT: After updating zombienet to version 1.3.58 I don't get above mentioned error anymore.

I now get another error that is not stopping the program but the error is getting logged continuously.

```
┌────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ Local Testnet ⚙ Added Boot Nodes                                                                                       │
├────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ /ip4/127.0.0.1/tcp/58081/ws/p2p/12D3KooWPA68TQCYEUd4mTUyd4ds93nhhK8QJjEknjWeJNQHXXcp                                   │
└────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
(node:66553) ExperimentalWarning: The Fetch API is an experimental feature. This feature could change at any time
(Use `zombienet-macos --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)

Error    fetching metrics from: http://127.0.0.1:58064/metrics

Error    fetching metrics from: http://127.0.0.1:58068/metrics

Error    fetching metrics from: http://127.0.0.1:58076/metrics

Error    fetching metrics from: http://127.0.0.1:58072/metrics

Error    fetching metrics from: http://127.0.0.1:58080/metrics

# and so on
```

The logs(they are the same for every parachain and validator):

```
2023-07-01 16:16:15.155  INFO main sc_cli::runner: Parity Polkadot    
2023-07-01 16:16:15.156  INFO main sc_cli::runner: ✌️  version 0.9.37-645723987cf    
2023-07-01 16:16:15.156  INFO main sc_cli::runner: ❤️  by Parity Technologies <admin@parity.io>, 2017-2023    
2023-07-01 16:16:15.156  INFO main sc_cli::runner:  Chain specification: Rococo Local Testnet    
2023-07-01 16:16:15.156  INFO main sc_cli::runner:   Node name: bob    
2023-07-01 16:16:15.156  INFO main sc_cli::runner:  Role: AUTHORITY    
2023-07-01 16:16:15.156  INFO main sc_cli::runner:  Database: RocksDb at /var/folders/07/snp6b9qn5fx3tvnw19zhp3jc0000gn/T/zombie-fb721b33984e1cd2280384de6398eed6_-14227-OnbVG2XaLP0F/bob/data/chains/rococo_local_testnet/db/full    
2023-07-01 16:16:15.156  INFO main sc_cli::runner: ⛓  Native runtime: rococo-9370 (parity-rococo-v2.0-0.tx18.au0)    
Error: 
   0: Failed to get runtime version: cannot deserialize module: UnknownOpcode(192)

  ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ BACKTRACE ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━
   1: backtrace::capture::Backtrace::create::hfad00a4f7b97e831
      at <unknown source file>:<unknown line>
   2: backtrace::capture::Backtrace::new::he4f988bb52487744
      at <unknown source file>:<unknown line>
   3: color_eyre::config::EyreHook::into_eyre_hook::{{closure}}::h3f9d14d3b2e64441
      at <unknown source file>:<unknown line>
   4: eyre::capture_handler::h2090812ea1c4f8f7
      at <unknown source file>:<unknown line>
   5: eyre::error::<impl eyre::Report>::from_std::h036cc641f7180345
      at <unknown source file>:<unknown line>
   6: polkadot::main::h1fe20747cba2fd19
      at <unknown source file>:<unknown line>
   7: std::sys_common::backtrace::__rust_begin_short_backtrace::h275865e011bf8454
      at <unknown source file>:<unknown line>
   8: std::rt::lang_start::{{closure}}::h819dadd8812ce71a
      at <unknown source file>:<unknown line>
   9: std::rt::lang_start_internal::hff0642c3803389b9
      at <unknown source file>:<unknown line>
  10: _main<unknown>
      at <unknown source file>:<unknown line>

Run with COLORBT_SHOW_HIDDEN=1 environment variable to disable frame filtering.
Run with RUST_BACKTRACE=full to include source snippets.
```

Comment: Hi @Szegoo, can you please add the version of zombienet are you using?

Comment: @pepoviola I am using zombienet version 1.3.18

Comment: That is an old version, can you try with the latest? https://github.com/paritytech/zombienet/releases/tag/v1.3.58 
Thanks!

Comment: @pepoviola That fixed my problem. I am now getting an error that is getting logged about every second: Error   fetching metrics from: http://127.0.0.1:58064/metrics

Comment: @pepoviola I edited the question so it now contains the new error I am getting.

Comment: Hi @Szegoo, are you running the binary from the release page or with `node.js`? If you are using node.js you need to have a version of node >= 18. Can you confirm please? Thanks!

Comment: @pepoviola I cloned the polkadot and substrate-parachain-template repositories. I checked out to the specific release and I built them locally by running `cargo build --release`. I did not use `node.js`

Comment: I mean for zombienet. But,  are you using `zombienet-macos` binary? can you run `./zombienet-macos version`?

Comment: @pepoviola Oh, I did not understand your question correctly, sorry. Yes, I can run `./zombienet-macos version`. I downloaded `zombienet-macos` the same way it is described [here](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/4692/how-do-i-spin-up-a-testnet-with-zombienet)

Comment: Hi @Szegoo, that answer have the link to the releases pages but the `wget` command is getting and old version. Can you run zombienet in debug mode
`DEBUG=zombie* zombienet-macos -p native spawn config.toml`, also can you check the logs of the nodes (you need to look the `/logs` directory inside of the temporal directory printed at start. Because could be the case that the node are crashing.

Comment: @pepoviola Looking at the logs was very useful. Thanks a lot for the tip. I managed to fix the issue by using another rust toolchain. I updated the question and you can see the logs there. If you post your comment as an answer I can accept it so that we can mark this issue as 'solved'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first let me point that the [answer](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/4692/how-do-i-spin-up-a-testnet-with-zombienet) you use as reference is pointing to download zombienet from the [releases](https://github.com/paritytech/zombienet/releases) page but the `wget` command used as example is downloading and old version.
One easy way to debug this kind of issues is to first running `zombienet` with `full` debug mode, this is managed with the `DEBUG` environment variable and you can run this way

```sh
DEBUG=zombie* zombienet-macos -p native spawn config.toml
```

Then, you can check the logs of the nodes (you need to look the `/logs` directory inside of the `temporal directory printed at start`. Because could be the case that the node are crashing.

Also, if you find something that doesn't work as expected or you think is a bug please open an [issue](https://github.com/paritytech/zombienet/issues) in zombienet's repo and we will check/fix.

Thanks for using zombienet and for you feedback!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with fetching metrics. After stopping the zombienet and restarting it, the problem went away. It is as if it is clearing some artifact the first time.

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work for me :/

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same issue however on spawn it was getting stuck on `Error    fetching metrics from: http://127.0.0.1:58485/metrics` until it timed out and got the network down, during this time `polkadot` relay validators and `cumulus` parachain collators were producing blocks however my parachain wasn't.

The fix was to build it on `nightly` channel which made the error to be logged but spawn not getting stuck there, it moved forward until successfully network launch confirmation and blocks are successfully being generated by my parachain.

Run on Apple M2.

```
[toolchain]
channel = "nightly-2023-01-01"
components = [ "rustfmt" ]
targets = [ "wasm32-unknown-unknown" ]
profile = "minimal"
```

Comment: http://127.0.0.1:58485 was the Prometheus Link assigned to my collator.